# SQL - One row for each number between

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two numbers in a single row (1 and 3) and I want to return a result set which contains one row for each number between the two.

```
declare @looprange table ( LoopStart int, LoopEnd int)
insert @looprange values (1,3)


select * from @looprange
```

How can I get this to return the following using sql server 2008 r2?

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: Only one row will be there in the table?

Comment: Correct. I'm wondering if there's a trick I can use - maybe cross joining the table to itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try using CTE:

```
declare @looprange table ( LoopStart int, LoopEnd int)
insert @looprange values (1,3)

;with T as(
  select * from @looprange
  union all
  select LoopStart+1, LoopEnd from T
  where LoopStart+1<=LoopEnd
)
select LoopStart From T
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```